# Windows 8 javascript html5 app not parsing xml

Tags: javascript, xml, html, windows-8, xml-parsing

My javascript XML parsing code works fine when I load it in firefox using local HTML & XML files, however when i build my app in visual studio 2012 (HTML5 javascript app)  using the same code it fails to parse the XML file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "pages/home/example.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;

//Content
txt = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("Symbol")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.write(txt + "  ");
```

Comment: why aren't you using the winjs libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You can get responseXML only after load.

```
var xmlDoc
xmlhttp.open("GET", "pages/home/example.xml", false);
xmlhttp.onload = function(){
  xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML
}
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: This results in the same problem. The app builds and then returns to the windows 8 start screen. No errors are displayed.

Comment: In case this Problem is still open, you have to send the request before you call the onload function ;)

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
                oReq.open("GET", 'pages/home/example.xml', false);
                
                oReq.send();
                oReq.onload = function(){
                    var xmlDoc = oReq.responseXML;
                }
                console.log(oReq.responseXML.xml);